# C drive backup and reistall OS

Tags: windows-8.1

my system C drive is corrupted and not able do to the OS without formatting C drive, Please suggest me how to install OS by taking existing files as backup.

I have most important file in my documents folder.

Comment: This is precisely why you are supposed to have a backup **before** the drive breaks, not afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

ok first things first, since you mentioned that your drive C is corrupted meaning only the software is corrupted, meaning your drive is still functional.

there are few ways you can do to back up your files inside your c: drive.

First and most common is to mount it to another computer as slave, and browse the directory where you need your important files are and copy it somewhere safe like if it is partitioned you can place it there and reformat your c:, you can also back it up on the drive of the computer where you mount it. or you can put it in an external drive such as USB or External USB Drive.

second way is used if you do not have an extra pc to mount it to and if your drive is partitioned you can create a bootable tool like hirens you can find the link here :

[Hirens Download](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd)

Hirens has a tool called MiniXP where you can boot up your pc using minixp and copy the files in your partitioned drive or usb.

hope this helps!